# How to avoid infinite loop of pressed keys in pyinput keyboard

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple script that listens to my `q` key, and when it gets pressed, it should fire 3 `q` press events. (If I am writing on word, and I type `q`, I want 3 additional `q`s to be typed).

The code me and chatGPT came up with loops infinetely, I guess because of the order variables get assigned and events get fired from the pyinput module.
Any suggestion on how to avoid the infinite loop?

Here is the code:

```
from pynput import keyboard

pressing = False  # Flag to control the behavior

def tap(key):
    keyboard.Controller().press(key)
    keyboard.Controller().release(key)

def three_q():
    tap("q")
    tap("q")
    tap("q")

def on_press(key):
    global pressing
    if pressing:
        return
    pressing = True
    try:
        key_char = key.char
        if key_char == "q":
            three_q()
        pressing = False
    except AttributeError:
        pass

def on_release(key):
    global pressing
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (on Windows) you can filter out events not generated by the actual keyboard using the `win32_event_filter` parameter.

```py
import pynput

def tap(key):
    pynput.keyboard.Controller().press(key)
    pynput.keyboard.Controller().release(key)

def three_q():
    tap("q")
    tap("q")
    tap("q")

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(key.char))
        if key.char == "q":
            three_q()
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(key))

def on_release(key):
    if key == pynput.keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False

with pynput.keyboard.Listener(
    on_press=on_press,
    on_release=on_release,
    win32_event_filter=lambda msg, data: not data.flags & 0x10
    ) as listener:

    listener.join()
```

Comment: Lifesaver!! This is exactly what I was looking for!